# slide over menu with objective C

Tags: ios, menu, slide

I just want to create a slide over menu for my app. I know that there are lot of Pods that I can use and very easy to use. but I found that they all do 'Slide out' not 'Slide over' menu's.

Slide out by I means the viewController move to side when the menu appear in the side of the screen. (like Facebook app).

But I want to create a menu that coming from the side of the screen and appear over the main VC. So when I press my menu button I don't want my main VC to slide. (like Uber app)

So can someone please tell me where to start doing this.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
__block CGRect sideMenuFrame    = self.sideMenuView.frame
        sideMenuFrame.origin.x  = - SIDE_MENU_WIDTH;
        self.sideMenuView.frame = sideMenuFrame;
        sideMenuFrame.origin.x  = 0;
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.sideMenuView duration:1.5f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{
            self.sideMenuView.frame = sideMenuFrame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];
```

This will make the view to slide to view from left. Do reverse animation to close.

Comment: Thank you.! your code really gives me more ideas..

Comment: That's what I planned to do - The Idea..That's why I didn't post the entire code. A programmer should be smart enough to grasp it.